# How to get the querystring parameters with Astro

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, astrojs

I'm using quite a new technology called Astro (https://astro.build/) to build a completely static, server side rendered page, shipping zero JS.

I have a page with a form that is a simple text input, when the user fills this in and clicks the submit button, it sends a GET request to an astro page.  The url will look something like this ....

/?search=1234

What I want to be able to do is get access to that querystring parameter in order to redirect my user to another static page /1234.

I am trying to access the quesrystring parameter with Astro.request, but the object, including the parameters attribute is completely empty.

Is there anyway to access the querystring parameters from a .astro page/file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reached out to the developers of Astro and eventually had an email back. This functionality is not possible with Astro, it is not a bug, rather a misunderstanding from me about how Astro works. The pages in Astro are rendered up-front and are entirely static.

Comment: It _is_ possible, either using vanilla JavaScript in a static page as already stated in @Someone's answer or on the server when using Astro's API routes.

Answer (score 20):

you can use [`Astro.url`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astrourl) (available since v1.0.0-rc).

e.g.

```
---
const search = Astro.url.searchParams.get('search')! || '';
---

{search ? <p>you searched for: {search}</p>}

<!-- rest of your template markup -->
```

Comment: This does not work, at least for SSG Astro; confusingly, Astro returns a URL object, but the searchParams are always empty, even if there really is a query parameter in the current window URL.

Comment: @NateGlenn This works when you put Astro into SSR mode. https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/

Comment: This doesn't work unless its SSR

Comment: If using SSG, you can hydrate the component and use a `<script>` tag to retrieve the parameters with client-side JS, as shown by @Someone's answer.

However, if you want this to affect your HTML code, you'll also have to replace that content with client-side JS. (In which case, SSR is probably the way to go.)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do the same thing, but this seems to be a bug in Astro that doesn't provide queryString parameters, but here is a way to implement it with just Vanilla javascript, but note that this can be only done client side as it is just javascript...

For the queryString:

```
localhost:3000/test?search=123
```

To get the parameters:

```
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
```

This approach can be seen in: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) as well

Comment: This approach works well for static pages (it's not a bug, just a consequence of the fact that astro is a static site generator). You can use a similar approach server-side if using Astro's API routes.

Answer (score 5):

This *is* possible with Astro and can be done using `<script></script>` tags in a `.astro` component.

Here's an `example.astro` file:

```html
---
<!-- imports go in here -->
---
<script>
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries());
console.log('params', params);
</script>

<!-- rest of your template markup -->
```

Documentation of using `<script></script>` tags in this way with Astro can be found here: https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/component-hydration/

(Scroll down to 'Can I Hydrate Astro Components?').

This feature is specifically there for simple DOM interactivity or cases where you need access to the JavaScript `window` or `document`.

Comment: There is no section labelled 'Can I Hydrate Astro Components?' on the page you provided a link for. You may be referring to deprecated docs.