# How can I access the url query parameters from an Astro file (server side)?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I'm unable to access the query parameters of an astro file.

Given the url `http://localhost:3000/example?hello=meow`:

How can I access `{hello: "meow"}` from within the `example.astro` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the querystring parameters with Astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70173939/how-to-get-the-querystring-parameters-with-astro)

Comment: @BadPiggie nope this is specifically using the query params on the client / front-end js.

Comment: What do you mean by `server side`.  The pages in `Astro` are rendered up-front and are entirely static

Comment: @BadPiggie there's a `output: "server"` mode where it does ssr instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're writing an API route, then you'd use a `.ts` or `.js` file [[source]](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/#ssr-and-routes).
In that, you can write a `get` method like this:

```
export async function get({request}) {
  // process the URL into a more usable format
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search)

  // set up a response object
  const data = {
    hello: params.get('hello'),
  };

  // this will yield { hello: 'meow' } on your Astro server console
  console.log(data)
  
  // return the response
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    status: 200
  }); }
```

From an `.astro` file you can access the url through `const { url } = Astro.request;` for SSR, I think. For static pages, you can do it through `const url = Astro.url;`  [[source]](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astrourl).

Comment: Hey Hasan, I just tried this and it did work with the `output: "server"` config here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qcqhjz?file=astro.config.mjs,src%2Fpages%2Fexample.json.ts

Comment: Can you add instructions on adding `output: "server"` to the config to your answer?

Comment: I followed the instructions on the official docs for the integration you need [[SSR Docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/)]. I used the [Vercel integration](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/), and all I had to do was type in `export default defineConfig({output: 'server', adapter: vercel()});`.

What integration do you have in mind?